# RadGrid Rendering differently in Different Machine of 100% Same Application when opening app in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, telerik, visual-studio-2013

I have a .NET 4.0 application which uses RadGrid in a web-page. When I open my page on 1st machine, I got the following HTML,

```
<div id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_radMainPanel">
   <div id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_radMain" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Metro">


                       <img width="64px" style='max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;' src="/Data/Images/2013_09_16_17_18_37_1837_30f9.jpg" />
                   </td><td>
```

and when I open the same page on second machine I got,

```
<div id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_radMainPanel">
    <div id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_radMain" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Metro">

    <table class="rgMasterTable" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_radMain_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col  />
        <col  />
        <col  />
        <col  />
        <col  />
        <col  />
...............................................................
```

The second one is correct but why my first machine does not show any table element which is the root cause.

`UPDATE:` After a lot of search, I was able to find the [answer at here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/10/23/messy-html-and-js-errors-when-you-install-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer, saved me hour and hours I think.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to you own question. I would vote it up. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UPDATE:` After a lot of search, I was able to find the [answer at here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/10/23/messy-html-and-js-errors-when-you-install-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

Comment: Imran Can you explain a bit detail about this settings?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes, problem is in Browser link that VS 2013 enable it by default.

This is connection between VS2013 and browsers that have opened solution. When debugging, VS2013 opens port and inserts js script that communicate with VS2013. Currently this feature is not so usefull. You can only refresh all browsers that opened your solution. In some cases this feature distorts HTML, so is in this case.

So how to disable it?

There are 3 ways:
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

- In the Browser Link dropdown menu, uncheck Enable Browser Link.
- In the Web.config file, add a key named “vs:EnableBrowserLink” with the value “false” in the appSettings section.
- In the Web.config file, set debug to false.