# telerik display problems in IIS Express

Tags: iis, express, telerik, radgrid

HI all recently I update my VS to 2013 version. the problem is VS 2013 uses IIS Express to show projects and Rad Grid doesn't show correctly in IIS express. I just don't know why

so I Install IIS itself and try it on IIS and everything becomes OK. I think there is a problem in show telerik component on IIS express.

does anybody have my problem too?

by the way I just write a line of javascript for my grid and on the execution it says there is error in get_dataitems function. but in grids that doesn't have this line of script everything is ok.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem.

This fixed it for me. Add

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

to your web.config.

[RadGrid Rendering differently in Different Machine of 100% Same Application when opening app in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513631/radgrid-rendering-differently-in-different-machine-of-100-same-application-when)

Comment: It disables the visual studio browser link - http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this 'issue' too. The solution (which is not the best but this one is the only one I know) I used for this problem is installing Visual Studio 2012 next to Visual Studio 2013, so you can also use VS2013 for other projects. Many parts of my website are displaying correctly but mainly Telerik Radgrids causing my problems.